Un-allowed DMA capable bus/device(s) detected - how to handle now that Microsoft has removed common fix?
This Super User answer provided the typical fix/workaround for when Windows 11 does not allow encryption due to the "Un-allowed DMA capable bus/device(s) detected" error being displayed in Windows' System Information.
Microsoft changed Windows to ignore the registry key required for this fix as of Windows 11 24H2 according to https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/oem-bitlocker
So, specifically for Windows 11 24H2 and later, how can one resolve the "Un-allowed DMA capable bus/device(s) detected" error so they can get native integrated encryption working in Microsoft's Windows 11?

I guess the short answer is "you can't." Windows not issuing fixes is their way of saying either "we don't want you using native integrated encryption" or "we just don't care," the former probably because of laziness, the latter probably because in a lot of people's opinion third party software is better. I agree that it's still really annoying, though. Reasons like these is why I left Windows many years ago...
